# polyline path to follow a draggable modal

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

- Here is what I am trying to do: **on click** (right now just click
  anywhere on the map)  will **draw the line and display a drag-able
  modal pop-up**, I have static coordinates set for the start point
  (which will later be dynamic), **but I would like the second point to
  find the draggable pop-up modal and stay with it even when it is
  dragged.**
- *I started the logic of following the mouse pointer continuously to get the end coordinates. But now thinking not the best method for
  finding and following modal.*

Below is what I have: *arcgis-js*

```
require([
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/MapView",
      "esri/Graphic",
      "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
      "esri/geometry/support/webMercatorUtils",
      "dojo/dom",
    ], 

  function init (Map, MapView, Graphic, GraphicsLayer, webMercatorUtils, dom) {
    var map = new Map({
      basemap: "topo-vector"     
    });
    var view = new MapView({
      container: "viewDiv",             
      map: map,
      center: [-80.96135253906438, 35.9411934679851],
      zoom: 3
    });

    var graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
    map.add(graphicsLayer);  

    // Create a line geometry
    var simpleLineSymbol = {
       type: "simple-line",
       color: [13,121,190, .9],
       style: "short-dash",
       width: 3
     };

     function showCoordinates(evt) {
        var point = view.toMap({x: evt.x, y: evt.y});
        //the map is in web mercator but display coordinates in geographic (lat, long)
        var mp = webMercatorUtils.webMercatorToGeographic(point);
        //display mouse coordinates
        dom.byId("info").innerHTML = mp.x.toFixed(3) + ", " + mp.y.toFixed(3);


       const coordinatesAx = -80.96135253906438;
       const coordinatesAy = 35.9411934679851;

       const coordinatesBx = mp.x.toFixed(3);
       const coordinatesBy = mp.y.toFixed(3);

       var polyline = {
         type: "polyline",
         paths: [
           [coordinatesAx, coordinatesAy], 
           [coordinatesBx, coordinatesBy]
         ]
       };
       var polylineGraphic = new Graphic({
         geometry: polyline,
         symbol: simpleLineSymbol
       })
       //graphicsLayer.add(polylineGraphic);
        document.getElementById("viewDiv").onclick = function fun() {
           graphicsLayer.add(polylineGraphic);
        }
      }
      view.when(function(){
        //after map loads, connect to listen to mouse move & drag events
        view.on("pointer-move", showCoordinates);
        //graphicsLayer.add(polylineGraphic);
      });
});
```

*And for the draggable modal using jQuery Kendo, that I'll call in a separate file (but shouldn't matter how this part is derived just want point B to follow modal/div elem).*

```
  <script>
     $("#dialog").kendoWindow({
        draggable: true
     });
  </script>
```

- here is a visual of what I am trying to accomplish. This would
  que on click, and the polyline would follow the `draggable modal`...*

[image]

**Mostly just struggling with getting one point of the line to find, and follow my draggable modal.** any ideas how I could accomplish this? on *`pointer-move` is clearly not the answer at all.*

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done some changes to your code
https://codepen.io/nettaben/pen/YzPrYrY

What is new:

- When the dialog is open and the mouse is moving ==> the line keeps "updating" (remove and add) and the dialog moves along with the cursor.
- On map click the "moveAlong" behavior stops
- On Kendo window dragstart the behavior is changed back to moveAlong

I had some issues with the Kendo drag events, still I believe this a good starting point to your question.

EDIT:
I've changed the code a bit, and prevented from the Kendo dragging to activate, with `ev.preventDefault()` so on dialog drag the behavior falls back to "moveAlong", and when the user clicks on the map, the modal will stop moving.
Kendo is a nice library, but if your question is about Kendo events - maybe nain SOF is a better place for this question.

Comment: Cheers. Please accept the answer if you find it helpful enough :)